# What is the simplest example of Spring OAuth2 with Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have recently built a REST API in Spring which I am consuming with a .Net C# client. At the moment there is no security so I would like to implement OAuth2. I am going to be the only user of my REST API so I don't need something complicated. Is there a simple example somewhere of Spring Security OAuth2 with java configuration? I looked in many places but either the examples use xml or they are too old and out of date or simply too complicated for what I need. I would appreciate any pointers with this.

By the way I looked at the Sparklr tutorial and github repo but they seem too complicated for what I need.

Comment: The best one I ever found http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-example.html

Comment: All are poiting to old spring versions < 2 and Oauth < 2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This one the best I ever found
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation

Comment: Thanks that does seem to be a better example. Now I have a different problem. I can get the access token but I get "Access is denied (user is anonymous" when I try to retrieve a resource using that token. Any ideas of whats going wrong?

Comment: If your resource server is a separate application then you need to configure the token store which will be the same as authorization server uses

Comment: I am following the vanilla example step by step and don't really get what I need to do with the token store. Any pointers?

Comment: And check the request's headers. It should be Authorization: Bearer your_token

Comment: I think I found the problem. I didn't have @EnableResourceServer on my Application class so the ResourceServer wasn't configured.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/vanilla is killer

Comment: Another one with Java configuration http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-example.html

Answer (score 7):

Below project provided a good example, in both server/client side.

https://github.com/bassemZohdy/Spring_REST_OAuth_Demo

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You see the examples of the spring project?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples