# OAuth 2 Flow for Office365 SMTP and JavaMail

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, office365, jakarta-mail

I have a Web Application in which one of the module was used for sending emails from the application to the clients. It was using basic authentication for sending emails but now there is a requirement for implementing OAuth2 Authentication in the process. I am new to this mailing and Authentication stuff. I would be really grateful if someone could explain me where to start and what process should i folllow.
It is a legacy project and we are not using Spring. Instead, we are using Struts 1.2 with Java 7.

Current JavaMail properties are :

```
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest example of Spring OAuth2 with Java configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088677/what-is-the-simplest-example-of-spring-oauth2-with-java-configuration)

Comment: We are not using Spring. It is some legacy project that uses Java 7 and Struts